# Use Range data type in Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid, rails-api

I am using Mongoid (4.0.0.alpha2) with rails-api (https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api).

I am looking for example on usage of "Range" (http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields) as datatype in my model.

Can I create an index on a field with datatype "Range"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A Range is mongoized(serizalized) as a hash with the keys max and min[1] for example:

```
(0..10)
```

will be stored in MongoDB as

```
{"max": 10, "min": 0}
```

so yes, you can create indexes over a range field but you would like to create the indexes to with max and min keys:

```
index(:"myfield.max" =>  1, :"myfield.min" => 1)
```

because if you create an index over a hash(myfield) it will not be used in a query like[2]:

```
MyDocument.where(:"myfield.min" => {:$gte => 1}, :"myfield.max" => {:$lte => 9})
```

[1] https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/1f8e12c5b03da1c9bd49bab12d86bef969868fb3/lib/mongoid/extensions/range.rb#L73

[2] http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/